# How to bind and replace old content of dropdown using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

I am getting an array of objects through AJAX for my page. However I am not able to bind the list to the previous dropdown option.

I am getting correct data in response, I want to set that data within my dropdown by replacing the old data with new one. Please provide a possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-info" style="text-align: right"><bean:message key="myKey" /></label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select id="dropdown_data" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
      <option value="">
        <bean:message key="myKey" />
      </option>
      <logic:iterate name="myForm" property="dataList" id="data">
        <option value="<bean:write name=" data " property="id " />">
          <bean:write name="data" property="name" />
        </option>
      </logic:iterate>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
function getUpdatedList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${myContext}/myUrl.do?method=getUpdatedList",
    data: {
      myDate: $('#myDate ').val()
    },
    success: function(response) {
      parseAndAddDatatForm(response)
    }
  });
}

function parseAndAddDatatForm(response) {
  $('#dropdown_data').empty();
  $(response).each(function() {
    var option = $('<option/>');
    option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);
    $('#dropdown_data').append(option);
  });
  $('#dropdown_data').select2();
}
```

[image: My dropdownlist]

Comment: Your code seems fine, although you shouldn't put the array of objects in to a jQuery object, just loop through it. Do you have a specific problem with this code? If so please edit the question to describe it, and also check the console for errors

Comment: No specific problem with the code, but my dropdown list should be displayed where there is the placeholder, "Please select a client". And currently, it is creating a new dropdown, which apparently gets the correct data but is displaying above my required dropdown (which doesn't replace the old dropdown.)

Answer (score 1):

From what I inferred from your Question is that you want to append some data into an existing Select tag.

This is my assumption about how your response looks:
    
     `{
      0: {
        'value':'Value 0',
        'label': 'Label 0'
      },
      1: {
        'value':'Value 1',
        'label': 'Label 1'
      }
    };`

Here is the Javascript for the required change:

```
function parseAndAddDatatForm(response) {
  //$('#dropdown_data').empty();
  $.each(response,function(key, responseValue) {
  var temp = response[key];
  var option = $('<option/>');
  option.attr('value', temp.value).text(temp.label);
  $('#dropdown_data').append(option);
 });
 $('#dropdown_data').select();
}
```

You can also find this snippet here:

[Code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery)